# iOS Dev: What does "original" mean in UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage?

Tags: ios

I have learning the [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) of iOS Apps Development. In "Work with View Controller" section, it teach me how to implement function to handle the event of user picking an image:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // The info dictionary contains multiple representation of the image, and this uses original
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // Set PhotoImageView to display the selected image
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage

        // Dismiss the picker
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I can't understand the meaning of "let selectedImage = ..." line, specifically the UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage part. The tutorial's explanation is:

> The info dictionary contains the ***original*** image that was selected in
>   the picker, and the ***edited*** version of that image, if one exists. To
>   keep things simple, you’ll use the original, unedited image for the
>   meal photo.

So, what is "original" and "edited" means ? What's the difference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerController` has an `allowsEditing` property which when set to true allows the user to edit still images or movies.

Hence `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` and `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` makes sense since they represent 2 different images, one which is the original and the other which has been edited by the user.